# Advice about how to animate the background of a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if you can offer me a better way of achieving the effect Ive created in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YLuKh/1/

Basically I would like to animate the background colour of the anchor tag revealing an image which I've done by positioning an anchor tag on top of a span on top of an image and then on hover animate the width of the span. Can anyone suggest a more straight forward way of doing this?

HTML

```
<ul id="test">
    <li>
        <a href="">This is the link</a>
        <span class="bg"></span>
        <img src="http://www.ritaxxii.org/wp-content/uploads/Luxury-Bedroom-Furniture-1.jpg" />
</li>
</ul>​
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var li_width = $('#test').find('li').width();
    console.log(li_width);


    $('#test').find('li').on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).find('.bg').stop().animate({
            width: '0'
        }, 200);
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).find('.bg').stop().animate({
            width: li_width
        }, 200);
    });

});​
```

Comment: Have you tried animating only the positioning of a css background image of an anchor tag?

Comment: Hey, yeah I've just come across that method there now. will definitely give that a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you can use the background position to do the animation. Here's a simple one using only background image positioning ( http://jsfiddle.net/3PESX/ )

```
$('a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 'background-position-x': '-700px'}, 300);
});
$('a').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 'background-position-x': '0'}, 300);
});​

a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px; 
    background: transparent url(http://jtrujillo.net/digital-photo-tutorials/8vs16bit/dgr1.jpg) 0 top no-repeat;
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}​

<a href="/">This is a link text</a>​
```

Beware that the background-position property is a composition of the x and y version. You cannot animate composite properties, you'll need to animate the X and Y version seperately. Alternatively you can use a css hook plugin that makes it possible. You can find those here: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks

Answer (score 1):

You can get a referance from this : http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a CSS3-only means of achieving what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
li {
    border: 1px solid #f90;
    width: 504px; /* width of the image, adjust to taste */
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: width 1s linear;
    -o-transition: width 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: width 1s linear;
    transition: width 1s linear;
}

li:hover a {
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s linear;
}

li a::after {
    content: url(http://www.ritaxxii.org/wp-content/uploads/Luxury-Bedroom-Furniture-1.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YLuKh/8/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have a lot of list items, you might want to consider event delegation to the #test element so you dont have to attach a bunch of different event listeners to each li tag

```
//attach one event listener for 'mouseover' and one for 'mouseout' on the test element
$('#test').on('mouseover', 'li', function(){
    //'this' is still the li element
    console.log( $(this)); 

    $(this).find('.bg').stop().animate({width: '0'},200);             
}).on('mouseout', 'li', function(){
    $(this).find('.bg').stop().animate({width: li_width},200);       
});
```